# Not able to see the page the event is firing with in SiteCatalyst

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm firing an event on a button click, and I have checked in omnibug/fiddler that it's firing and I'm seeing it in the report. However, I'm not able to see a breakdown of the pages it's happening on. Is this because it's firing on a click event and not a pageload? If so, what's the best way to set up so that I get a count of the number of times a button is clicked and have the ability to break this down by page (i.e. if it's a global or semi-global element)

Comment: dupe `pageName` to an `eVar` and use the `eVar` as your dimension

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using s.tl call with the button click - that means it wont increment page view and wont track pagename (even if you pass it with call it will get stripped)

Either have s.t call and have pagename with it (not an ideal way) else approach suggested by  Crayon would help.